# How to implement a selection control like Outlook with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, syncfusion

I am creating an event screen like Outlook's. The issue I am coming across is that the autocompletebox I am using from `Syncfusion` doesn't automatically grow in height as more tokens are added.

The current workflow is exactly like outlooks. When the control is clicked on, it brings you to another page where you can select tokens. On return, the selected items populate the autocomplete circled below.

The approach I currently took is to have a listview. Scrolling is disabled for the listview since the page resides in a scrollview and nested scrollviews aren't recommended for xamarin. The height of the listview is dependent on the number of selecteditems.

I am wondering if there's another approach or control that would be more suited for my situation?  Or if someone has come across a autocomplete control where the height will grow.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a scrollView  and add subViews to it or just use a listView and custom ViewCell to display what you want? I downloaded a sample [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfautocomplete/getting-started) and found the autocompletebox of Syncfusion won't automatically grow by default. Add your codes and we can check it.

Comment: Hi @jack, I also included the approach I'm currently using is a listview, I would of preferred the autocomplete since it's much more clean. May I ask for a quick link by what you mean of adding subviews? Seems to be iOS specific, I also can't find any tutorials on it.

Comment: Use a listView in your case is better. Adding subviews here I mean, instead of nesting  a listView inside a scrollview, you can use a scrollView as backGround View and add those subViews which you want to this scrollView.